# Mesos: Web UI cannot connect to the server

Tags: apache-mesos

I'm newbie to Mesos and DC/OS. I set up DC/OS using vagrant and all seemed to go well at first. I am on Mac Yosemite, Virtualbox Version 5.0.26,  vagrant version 1.8.5 with the following patch: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/pull/7611.

I launched the DC/OS stack with following command: vagrant up m1 a1 a2 a3 a4 p1 boot. And I can see all instances launched and running, I can log in into each of them via ssh.  I can also see the web UI at: m1.dcos. In this UI, I managed to launch kafka and cassandra. The only problem is that after a few minutes, the UI stops working. I get the following error messages in the UI:

```
Cannot Connect With The Server
```

or:
    Unable to complete request due to service [adminRouter] unavailability

The following site (https://github.com/dcos/dcos-vagrant/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md), has an entry for a similar issue and suggests running: service dcos-cosmos restart. The UI is still not accessible although all my 7 DC/OS nodes are up and running in Virtualbox.

I can ssh into each of these VMs but the whole web UI is not responding. If I use another browser and try m1.docs, the site is not reachable at all. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

For anybody who might come to experience the same issue, it appears there is an SSH issue with vagrant 1.8.5. Downgrading to 1.8.4 works for me. See https://github.com/dcos/dcos-vagrant/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md#ssh-authentication-failure